# How do I enable AES-NI (hardware acceleration) for Node.js crypto on Linux?

Tags: encryption, aes

I wrote a basic function to test the speed of the AES-256-CBC mode of the Node.js built-in crypto functions.  These functions use OpenSSL, so they should support AES-NI, but when I correctly enable AES-NI and do a command-line test of OpenSSL the encryption speed is ~350MB/s on OpenSSL and only ~100MB/s on Node.js Crypto.

I used [this answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/35036/different-performance-of-openssl-speed-on-the-same-hardware-with-aes-256-evp-an) to enable OpenSSL AES-NI in the command line and ran it as follows:

`openssl speed -evp aes-256-cbc`

My question is, how do I make the speed of the Node.js crypto functions for AES match that of OpenSSL run in the command line?  I suspect the reason is failure to use AES-NI

Comment: I suspect part of the reason is that there's an additional layer of abstraction between Node.js and the native OpenSSL code. However, this is purely a software question and is not really on-topic for this site.

Comment: Yes, I figured that much, but I was hoping someone might know how to activate or fix it.  Also, how do I know what is on topic for this site?  It would seem people ask similar questions fairly often

Comment: Under 'help' there's an answer to the question "What questions can I ask here?".